Wordpress over Cloudflare admin page issues
I've installed Wordpress on Digital Ocean using their one-click marketplace Wordpress installation. I haven't configured SSL on the server as we're using Cloudflare for that.
On Cloudflare we have Flexible SSL mode set up and Always Use HTTPS is on.
With this set up the example Wordpress page works fine, but when I tried to log into the admin dashboard I noticed the styles were missing as the css urls were blocked because they were using the non-ssl http urls. Also, the log in didn't work.
In the backing MySQL database the wp_options table had both siteurl and home set to the http version of the url. After changing them to https urls, I'm getting the "too many redirects error" when I try to access the /wp-admin page.
